# Custom modal with text input or any other input in React Native?

Tags: react-native

So the thing is, I create a custom Tab button that has a modal inside of it. But the problem is that I can't seem to add inputs inside this modal, I can only add text :/ Can someone help me with this, please?

This is a bit of the modal code with the bad input that gives me "Invalid hook call." error :

```
renderContent = () => {
    const {data} =this.props
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
    return (
        <View>
       <FlatList
          style = {{marginBottom: 20}}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator= {false}
          data={data}
          renderItem= {this.renderItem}
          extraData={data}
          keyExtractor= {(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          contentContainerStyle= {{
              paddingBottom: 40
          }}

       />

<TextInput placeholder="Enter something..." 
                                   value={inputValue} style={styles.textInput} 
                                   onChangeText={(value) => setInputValue(value)} />
       
    </View> )
}
renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (

        <View style={{height: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text style= {{fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'normal', color: '#182E44'}}>{item.name}</Text>
           
        </View>
    )
}
renderSeparator= () => {
    return (
        <View
        style={{
            opacity: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: '#182E44',
            height: 1
        }}
        />
        
    
    )
}

render() {
 let {show } =this.state
 const {onTouchOutside, title} =this.props
 
return(
    
 <Modal
    animationTyp={'fade'}
    transparent={true}
    visible= {show}
    onRequestClose={this.close}
    >
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
             backgroundColor: '#000000AA',
              justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                  {this.renderOutsideTouchable(onTouchOutside)}
                  <View style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                      width: '100%',
                      borderTopRightRadius: 10,
                      borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
                      paddingHorizental: 10,
                      maxHeight: deviceHeight * 0.4
                  }}>
               
        
                      {this.renderTitle()}
                      {this.renderContent()}
                    

                  </View>
              </View>
           </Modal>
)
```

Comment: Can you share the code or a screenshot of what you are trying

Comment: Thank you for anwsering! I just updated the post with the code ^^

Comment: const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("") // invalid hook call , you cannot use useState hook in a class component , so declare state in initial props setup for your class component

Comment: So how does it become?